# using of input list PHP

Tags: php

when i run my page and select a item from my input list, the list filed by 'id_uesr', i need id_user' to send to another database but i do not want showed when i've choose a item.

```
<?php   

$user_id =$fgmembersite->UserID();

   $db_host = 'localhost';
   $db_name= 'site';
   $db_table2= 'tablesite';
   $db_user = 'root';
   $db_pass = '';

$con2 = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con2) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");

$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT *
                       FROM  $db_table2 WHERE id_user != '$user_id'",$con2);
    echo'* نام کاربری که به او خدمت داده اید: ','<br/>';                       

    echo'<input list="users" name="users">';
    echo'<datalist id="users">  ';             
while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{ 
   echo '<option value="'.$amch['id_user'].'">'.$amch['username'].'</option>';
}
echo '</datalist> <br/>';

?>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JTFRage look on picture adder. as you see, after choose a name, that show me digits of his/her id

Comment: why not use select then? or change value with name as well

Comment: @MujnoiGyulaTamas because i want to send id_user after selecting to a database. 2. in select mode cant search and it is big problem if there is many users. i used a hidden iput but that sends last record id :(

Comment: i would suggest using chosen then https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ its a jquery plugin which will let you do exactly what you want

Comment: Why are you mixing SQL and HTML with controller code? This is extremely sloppy code!

Answer (score 0):

When you are displaying the datalist, the value attribute is what is being displayed. When you select an option, the value is what is being returned. So in your solution, you have id_user as the value, but you are displaying the username. When you make the selection, the option value is return (id_user).

**You have:**

```
echo '<option value="'.$amch['id_user'].'">'.$amch['username'].'</option>';
```

**You need:**

```
echo '<option value="'.$amch['username'].'">';
```

Comment: i do not have id_username in my database!

Comment: i want after choose show me username. when i choose username it value change to his username

Comment: Then you need to have the value of the option as 'username'.